# Interesting limit involving gamma function

Tags: calculus, limits, gamma-function

$$\displaystyle  \lim_{n \to \infty}{\dfrac{\Gamma\left(\frac{p}{m}+n+1\right) \Gamma\left(\frac{q}{m} + \frac{n}{2} + 1\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{q}{m}+n+1\right) \Gamma\left(\frac{p}{m} + \frac{n}{2} + 1\right)}}$$

This is from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2044643/does-this-have-a-closed-form-lim-n-to-infty-left-prod-r-0n-2-left-f).

If we add one more variable -

> $$\displaystyle L(p,q,m,t) = \lim_{n \to \infty}{\dfrac{\Gamma\left(\frac{p}{m}+n+1\right) \Gamma\left(\frac{q}{m} + \frac{n}{t} + 1\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{q}{m}+n+1\right) \Gamma\left(\frac{p}{m} + \frac{n}{t} + 1\right)}}$$

Then, the results I got from W|A are really interesting. They seem to follow the pattern which says

> $\displaystyle L(p,q,m,t) = \dfrac{1}{t^{|p-q|/m}}$

If it is indeed true, how to prove it? Factorial approximations did not lead me anywhere.

Comment: Have you tried taking logarithms and then applying Stirling's formula?

Comment: What  Dominik  suggests works like a charm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the same spirit as Dominik's answer, consider $$A=\displaystyle L(p,q,m,t) = \lim_{n \to \infty}{\dfrac{\Gamma\left(\frac{p}{m}+n+1\right) \Gamma\left(\frac{q}{m} + \frac{n}{t} + 1\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{q}{m}+n+1\right) \Gamma\left(\frac{p}{m} + \frac{n}{t} + 1\right)}}$$ and take logarithms.

Now use Stirling approximation $$\log\left( \Gamma\left(x\right)\right)=x (\log (x)-1)+\frac{1}{2} \left(\log (2 \pi
   )-\log(x)\right)+O\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$ Apply to each term and simplify as much as you can.

Now, apply to the result Taylor again for large values of $n$ to get (to second order)

$$\log(A)=\frac{(q-p) \log \left(\frac{1}{t}\right)}{m}+\frac{ (q-p) (m+p+q)(t-1)}{2 m^2 n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\tag 1$$ which makes the limit to be $$\log(A)=\frac{(q-p) \log \left(\frac{1}{t}\right)}{m}=\frac{(p-q) \log \left(t\right)}{m}\implies A= L(p,q,m,t)={t^{\frac{p-q}{m}}}$$ The second term in $(1)$ shows how the limit is approached.

Answer (score 4):

From [Abramowitz and Stegun](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_257.htm) we know
$$\ln \Gamma(x) = x \ln(x) - \frac{1}{2} \ln(x) - x + \frac{\ln(2\pi)}{2} + O(\tfrac{1}{x}) \qquad (x \to \infty)$$

Applying this formula here yields

$$\begin{align*}
\ln \Gamma\left(\frac{p}{m} + \frac{n}{t}\right) &= \left(\frac{p}{m} + \frac{n}{t}\right) \ln\left(\frac{p}{m} + \frac{n}{t}\right) - \left(\frac{p}{m} + \frac{n}{t}\right) + \frac{\ln(2\pi)}{2} + O(\tfrac{1}{n}) \\
&= \left(\frac{p}{m} + \frac{n}{t}\right) \ln(n) - \frac{n}{t} - \frac{p}{m}
 + \left(\frac{p}{m} + \frac{n}{t}\right) \ln \left(\frac{1}{t} + \frac{p}{mn}\right) + \frac{\ln(2\pi)}{2} + o(1).
\end{align*}$$

After cancelling some terms, we get
$$\ln \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{p}{m} + \frac{n}{t}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{q}{m} + \frac{n}{t}\right)} = \frac{p-q}{m} \ln(n) - \frac{p - q}{n} + \frac{p - q}{m} \ln\left(\frac{1}{t}\right) + \frac{n}{t} \ln \left(\frac{\frac{1}{t} + \frac{p}{mn}}{\frac{1}{t} + \frac{q}{mn}}\right) + o(1).$$

Now note that
$$\frac{n}{t} \ln \left(\frac{\frac{1}{t} + \frac{p}{mn}}{\frac{1}{t} + \frac{q}{mn}}\right) = \frac{1}{t} \ln\left(\frac{\left(1 + \frac{pt}{mn}\right)^n}{\left(1 + \frac{qt}{mn}\right)^n}\right) = \frac{1}{t}\ln\left(\frac{\exp(pt/m)}{\exp(qt/m)}\right) + o(1) = \frac{p - q}{m} + o(1).$$

After cancelling some more terms we get
$$\ln \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{p}{m} + n\right) \Gamma\left(\frac{q}{m} + \frac{n}{t}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{q}{m} + n\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{p}{m} + \frac{n}{t}\right)} = \frac{q - p}{m} \ln(\tfrac{1}{t}) + o(1) = \frac{p - q}{m} \ln(t) + o(1).$$

Using the formula $\Gamma(x + 1) = x \Gamma(x)$ we see that the limit in the last equation is equal to $\ln L(p, q, m, t)$, which finally shows

$$L(p, q, m, t) = t^{(p-q)/m}.$$

Comment: Your final equation should have a mod. It looks ambiguous like this.

Comment: @KartikSharma What do you mean? I don't see how the formula could be ambiguous.

Comment: The original limit is symmetric for $p,q$ but your formula is not symmetric.

Comment: That's because the original formula is incorrect. It is also pretty obvious that it is incorrect in this way, since $L(p, q, m, t) = L(q, p, m, t)^{-1}$.

Comment: I don't get you. Check @Claude Leibovici 's answer. Now, which answer should I mark as correct?

Comment: I have mixed up $p$ and $q$ near the end. Now the result should be correct.